# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'BannerModel'

Tags: flutter, hashmap

every time i get that error and idk why?

```
class HomeModel {
  late bool status;
  late DataHomeModel data;

  HomeModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    data = DataHomeModel.fromjson(json['data']);
  }
}

class DataHomeModel {
  List<BannerModel> banners = [];
  List<ProductModel> products = [];
  DataHomeModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json['banners'].forEach((element) {
      banners.add(element);
    });
    json['products'].forEach((element) {
      products.add(element);
    });
  }
}

class BannerModel {
  int? id;
  String? image;
  BannerModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    image = json['image'];
  }
}

class ProductModel {
  late int id;
  late dynamic price;
  late dynamic oldprice;
  late dynamic discount;
  late String name;
  late String image;
  late bool infavourite;
  late bool incart;

  ProductModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    price = json['price'];
    discount = json['discount'];
    oldprice = json['old_price'];
    image = json['image'];
    name = json['name'];
    incart = json['in_cart'];
    infavourite = json['in_favourites'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error most likely comes from the following class while you try to convert the elements to `BannerModel` elements.

```
class DataHomeModel {
  List<BannerModel> banners = [];
  List<ProductModel> products = [];
  DataHomeModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json['banners'].forEach((element) {
      banners.add(element);
    });
    json['products'].forEach((element) {
      products.add(element);
    });
  }
}
```

At the line above code, you do not convert the items into the models that you need. So you need to fix that.

```
class DataHomeModel {
  List<BannerModel> banners = [];
  List<ProductModel> products = [];
  DataHomeModel.fromjson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    json['banners'].forEach((element) {
      banners.add(BannerModel.fromJson(element));
    });
    json['products'].forEach((element) {
      products.add(ProductModel.fromJson(element));
    });
  }
}
```